# Logic buffers with discrete propagation delay

Tags: buffer, delay, propagation

I want to have a circuit (for this matter a logic buffer) with a discrete propagation delay. It can be 5 ns, 10 ns or 15 ns, but I want deviations to be within 10-20% of these values.

Where do I start to look for these kinds of parts?

I need at least 6 of these in the design.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ds1100l.pdf

Comment: @stretch ohhhh you are the best, thank you!!! but it cost's $5 8-|

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is called delay dispersion

Comment: A deviation this small will be difficult to achieve over normal variations in temperature, supply voltage, and manufacturing. Please tell us what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: is that pulse clocked, i.e. is there some underlying clock, only at whose edges a pulse might begin, end or be "valid"?

Comment: It's about balancing PWM switching of several MOSFETs

Answer (score 4):

A properly terminated low loss [transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) will have a nearly constant delay over a wide range of signal frequencies. This means that you can just use a length of cheap coaxial cable, a line driver (strong buffer) at one end, and a line receiver plus termination resistor at the other end. The delay through that coax cable will be exactly proportional to its length, which means that you can adjust it to be as long or short as you want (within reasonable limits). Depending on your signal source, you might not even need a line driver or receiver at all. The delay of a somewhat decent coax cable is very stable over time and also over temperature (0.8ps per meter Kelvin, according to [this paper](https://scipp.ucsc.edu/milagro/memos/hoffman052101.pdf)). 10% deviation is achievable quite easily this way - in fact, you can probably get down to 1% or better.

You could use 75 Ohm coax (i.e. RG-59) because it's cheap, easy to drive, and readily available - it's used for television. The only problem is that you'll need quite a bit of cable (about 1 meter). You can roll it up, though.

This technique was used a lot in [Tektronix oscilloscopes](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/Delay_line) and it's [still used](http://www.coax.co.jp/en/semi/delayline) in RF circuits.

Comment: Awesome idea. How didn't i think about it? Anyway, do you think microstrip would hold within 10-20% over the normal temp range? I think PCB is stable enough.

Comment: 10% should not be an issue with microstrip. It might get pretty long, though, but it'll have the advantage that you can select its impedance freely (so you can choose it to be higher, i.e. 150 Ohms, to waste less power). If you make the trace meander, you could place a ground trace between the individual parts of the trace that run in parallel in order to minimize cross-coupling. This is actually how delay matching is done on high-frequency parallel buses.

Comment: twisted pair wire with LVDS drivers and receivers may also be an option.

Comment: Twisted pairs with differential signaling is actually how it was done in the Cray-1 supercomputer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-1#/media/File:Cray-1-p1010227.jpg